# ¿Como armar la siguiente petición post? PHP + CURL

Tags: php, post, php5, curl

necesito armar la siguiente:

```
 curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-cards/ \ -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ -H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token " \ -d '{ "number": "4417119669820331", "type": "visa", "expire_month": 11, "expire_year": 2015, "first_name": "Joe", "last_name": "Shopper", "billing_address": { "line1": "52 N Main St.", "city": "Johnstown", "country_code": "US", "postal_code": "43210", "state": "OH", "phone": "408-334-8890" } }'
```

He logrado hacer lo siguiente, pero no funciona:

```
    public function addUser($pan, $expdate, $cvv)
    {
    //1-> Filtro los datos
        $pan = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $pan);
        $expdate = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $expdate);
        $cvv = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $cvv);
    //2-> Defino variables necesarias
        $url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-cards";
        $authorization = "Authorization: Bearer ".$this->token;
    //3-> Configuro la petición
        $ch = curl_init(); // abrimos la sesión cURL 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); //Indicamos que es POST
    //4-> Se arman los parametros para ser enviados
        $params = "[number=$pan";
        $params.= "&type=\"visa\"";
        $params.= "&expire_month=".substr($expdate, 4, 5);
        $params.= "&expire_year=".substr($expdate, 0, 4);
        $params.= "&first_name=\"\"";
        $params.= "&last_name_name=\"\"";
    /*  $params.= [
                    "line=\"\"",
                    "city=\"\"",
                    "country_code=\"\"",
                    "postal_code=\"\"",
                    "phone=\"\"",
x                 ];
    */  
        $params.= "[";
           $params.="line=\"\"";
           $params.="&city=\"\"";
           $params.="&country_code=\"\"";
           $params.="&postal_code=\"\"";
           $params.="&phone=\"\"";
        $params.= "]]";

        //$params.= "&billing_address"=>array("line1=\"\""."&city=\"\""."country_code=\"\""."&postal_code=\"\""."&state=\"\""."&phone=\"$
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params); // asigno los parámetros
        // body
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization));
        // recibimos la respuesta y la guardamos en una variable
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $remote_server_output = curl_exec ($ch); 
        // cerramos la sesión cURL
        curl_close ($ch);
        //Descodifico la respuesta
        $res = json_decode($remote_server_output, true);
        //Retorno la respuesta
        return $res;
    }
```

**Actualización** Me da el siguiente error usando el metodo http_build_query:

```
$auxiliar = array("number"=>"$pan", "type"=>"visa", "expire_month"=>substr($expdate, 4, 5), 
"expire_year"=>substr($expdate, 0, 4), "first_name"=>"Pepe", "last_name"=>"Pepito", "billing_address"=>array("line1"=>"J2",
                                                                                                   "city"=>"Barcelona",
                                                                                                   "country_code"=>"ES",
                                                                                                   "postal_code"=>"08002",
                                                                                                   "state"=>"Cataluya",
                                                                                                   "phone"=>"333333333"
                                                                                                  ));
```

**

```
(
    [name] => VALIDATION_ERROR
    [debug_id] => 6fa659ed4c0e
    [message] => Invalid request - see details
    [details] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [location] => body
                    [issue] => Unrecognized token 'number': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN line: 1, column: 8
                )
        )
)
```

**

La solución es enviar un json y no parámetros.
Para eso hay que editar el código de @Jakala y agregar:

1- `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($params) , $authorization));`

2- eliminar el `http_build_query` por `$params = json_encode($params);`

Answer (score 1):

de momento, veo cosas que te faltan en el curl:

1.- no indicas a curl los parametros. Esto lo debes hacer despues de haber definido la cadena $params:

```
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
```

2.- no indicas los headers:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$this->token
));
```

3.- no llamas a curl para ejecutar la llamada y obtener datos. Esto lo debes hacer al finalizar todo lo anterior:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

A partir de aqui, $response deberia ser un json, asi que es muy posible que quieras transformarlo con json_decode(). Echale un vistazo.

**NOTA:** respecto a los parametros, Curl requiere un formato de query de url, y en tu caso estas componiendo una cadena mezcla de json y query... (Es posible que si quitas los corchetes funcione, pero no seguro. )

Para solucionarlo, php tiene una funcion llamada http_build_query, a la que le pasas un array asociativo, y te devuelve una cadena similar a la que estas construyendo a mano. Te recomiendo que utilices dicha funcion. Te sera mas facil operar el array por las claves y luego con llamar a esta funcion crear la cadena de consulta mas facilmente.

para definir los parametros, podrias hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
    $params = [
            'number' => $this->number,
        'type' => $this->type,
        'expire_month' => $this->expireMonth,
        'expire_year' => 2015,
        'first_name' => 'Joe',
        'last_name' => 'Shopper',
        'billing_address' => [
            'line1' => '52 N Main St.',
            'city' => 'Johnstown',
            'country_code' => 'US',
            'postal_code' => 43210,
            'state' => 'OH',
            'phone' => 408-334-8890,
        ]
    ];
$params = http_build_query($params);
```

Ahora, despues del http_build_query, tienes una cadena de string en la que los parametros estan construidos segun clave=valor y separados por &. He utilizado $this->name y algun otro para dar el ejemplo, pero ahi deberas poner los de tu propio objeto o de los parametros que tengas en tu funcion

Comment: Perdón, no puse todo el código completo porque el error lo tengo en definir los parámetros, acabo de actualizar el código a la versión completa. No sé como armar los parámetros tal y como lo requiere paypal, sin embargo, creo que el resto de cosas están super bien.

Comment: los parametros en el curl deben ir como una query de url. Por ello, te sugiero que utilices un array asociativo, pongas clave y valor para los valores que necesites, y utilices la funcion http_build_query, que te crea la cadena con el formato que necesites. He actualizado la respuesta para explicarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a intentarlo y en un rato te comentaré el resultado

Comment: los parámetros que tienen que ir vacíos, ¿se representan como array("parametroVacio"=>"") ? porque en la URL queda como parametroVacio=& y creo que me eso me está dando error

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la pregunta con el código que yo estaba utilizando para generar los parámetros. Intentaré usar tu código, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: El error que publiqué con mi código aún persisten con tu ejemplo, es curioso.